# Length of the string from address of variable(&variable) - Embedded C

Tags: c++, embedded, uart, texas-instruments, code-composer

How can I find the length of the string from address of variable(&variable) ? Below is the code :

```
SimpleProfile_GetParameter(SIMPLEPROFILE_CHAR7, &newValue); // Hello123
const char echoPrompt[] = "Print From BLE characters:\r\n";
UART_write(uart, echoPrompt, sizeof(echoPrompt)); // Output : Print From BLE characters: | Size : 29
UART_write(uart, &newValue, sizeof(&newValue)); // Output : Hello | Size : 4
```

I am using this code in [Code Composer Studio (CCS)](http://www.ti.com/tool/CCSTUDIO). I need to print the string in UART, Where I need to specify number of character in the string.

I need "Hello123" to be printed instead its printing "Hello"

Comment: `sizeof(&newValue)` is getting the size of a pointer, not an array.

Comment: If you want the length of a string, use `strlen()`.

Comment: Can, I able to get the size of array ?. I revised my question

Comment: Is the "string" a proper null-terminated string? Then use `strlen` to get its length. Otherwise you can not get the size of some memory by just using a pointer.

Comment: Currently it was in datatype "unsigned char"

Comment: The use of `&` in the second `UART_write()` argument `&newValue` is incorrect; the type should be `char*` not `char**`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&newValue` is a pointer, so `sizeof(&newValue)` returns the size of a pointer, not the string it points to. Assuming `newValue` is a null-terminated string, use `strlen()`.

`sizeof` operates at compile time, it can't get the size of a string that's constructed dynamically.

You should also do that with `echoPrompt`, because `sizeof` includes the trailing null byte, and you probably don't need to write that.

```
UART_write(uart, echoPrompt, strlen(echoPrompt));
UART_write(uart, &newValue, strlen(&newValue));
```

Comment: `strnlen` will be just a bit safer in case the string in not correctly terminated

Comment: Assuming his implementation has `strnlen()`.

Comment: strlen working fine. strnlen giving me error as "error #10234-D: unresolved symbols remain"

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr `strnlen` is a POSIX function, it's not standard C.

Comment: In this case `sizeof(echoPrompt) - 1` would also have worked.

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr : You would do well perhaps to wrap the behaviour in a new function `UART_writestr()` to avoid the need to call `strlen()` all over the place, so for example you would have just:  `UART_writestr( uart, newValue );` and then have the function call `strlen` and `UART_write` internally.

Comment: @Clifford True, although if the declaration were ever to change to something like `char echoPrompt[MAXSIZE] = "...";` it would be wrong. `strlen()` is more general and flexible.